# Entity Framework How to query data in a Navigation property table

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a the following setup

```
m_handsets = From p In RL.App.TComEntities.tblTelephoneNumbers _
                                               Where p.companyId = m_CompanyID _
                                               Select p

m_handsets = DirectCast(m_handsets, ObjectQuery(Of RL.TelephoneNumbers)).Include("tblCalls")
```

where m_handsets is defined as

```
Private m_handsets As IQueryable(Of RL.tblTelephoneNumbers)
```

which works as expected however what I want to do know is query the Navigation property (tblCalls) so I can do something like the following

```
From p In m_handsets.tblCalls 
Where m_handsets.tblCalls.price > 100
```

but I have no idea of the proper syntax, can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

I think the complexity comes here because in this instance I could have 5 tblTelephoneNumbers in m_handsets and then x amount of calls for that particular telephone number. I am interested in the tblCalls for each but I would like to filter them all for each tblTelehoneNumber.

Entity Diagram which (hopefully) should illustrate further 
[image: diagram]

So I currently know all the handsets that are associated with the company I am interested in. I can also see the calls loaded as a navigation property in debug mode, but I want to say is take this filter (in this example price>100 and apply it to all handsets->calls

Comment: So, do you want to filter on tblCalls and not include all of them when selecting and returning m_handsets, or you only want to select those tblCalls that belongs to m_handsets and return tblCalls?

Comment: An Entity diagram is usually a good idea in cases like this to make the question clearer.

Comment: Absolutely, agree with @Hightechrider. It is not clear on the structure of your model. (mainly, the multipicity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand your question correctly, then you have 2 solutions to accomplish this:
In both solution you'll see that I remove the *Include* method since *Include* does NOT allow you to filter the related data.

**1. Filtered Projection (Returns Anonaymous Type)**:

```
Dim results = From p In RL.App.TComEntities.tblTelephoneNumbers _
              Where p.companyId = m_CompanyID _
              Select New With {.Handsets = p, _
                               .tblCalls = p.tblCalls.Where(Function(t) t.price > 100)}
```

However, it might not be desirable in all situations as it gives a collection of anonymous type objects.

**2. Two Tracked Queries (Returns EntityObjects):**

This one gives you a collection of your entityobject tblTelephoneNumbers:

```
Dim m_handsets = (From p In RL.App.TComEntities.tblTelephoneNumbers _
                  Where p.companyId = m_CompanyID Select p).ToList()

Dim m_tblCalls = (From t In RL.App.TComEntities.tblCalls _
                  Where t.price > 100 Select t).ToList();

ForEach(Dim t In m_tblCalls) 
    m_handsets.Single(Function(h) h.ID = t.tblTelephoneNumberID).tblCalls.Add(t)
End ForEach
```

**3. Leveraging Attach Method (Returns EntityObjects)**:

The last and probably the best and most elegant solution is to use [*EntityCollection.Attach*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738589.aspx) Method along with [*EntityCollection.CreateSourceQuery*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896438.aspx):

```
foreach (var tel in m_handsets) {

    IQueryable<tblCalls> sourceQuery = tel.tblCalls.CreateSourceQuery()
                                                   .Where(c => c.price > 100);
    tel.tblCalls.Attach(sourceQuery);
}
```

Sorry for any VB syntax mistake, I wrote them all off the top of my head.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance Is this right? Does this not defeat the purpose of include as I am having to go and get all data from data calls filter it and then tie it back to a tbltelephoneNumbers, where the navigation property has already the steps other than filter it?

Comment: Like I mentioned, the point really is that *there is absolutely no way to filter included data with include() mehtod.* My both suggested ways are kind of workarounds for this limitation of include method and I just added yet another way to my answer, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I like option 3 as that kind of makes sense to me and was also an approach I had discovered in the meantime almost by accident :-)

Comment: No problem. Honestly, I answered this question a few times before in SO and most of the guys were happy with either option 1 or 2, but in this case I decided to come up with a better solution and yes I also like the last solution more than the others.