# navigating many-to-many via include in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a many to many relationship in EF4 with the following entities:

[Student] - [Class] - [Student_Class]

Moreover i have a [School] entity with a FK on [Student].

If i want to have all the Students of my school i do:

```
context.School.Include("Student")
```

but if i want to have the 1rst class of my Students in my school ?

```
context.School.Include("Student").Include("Student_Class").Where(...
```

i did not manage to make this thing work...
Can you help ?
Also is it more intelligent to write a full Linq select?
Thanks
John

Comment: It looks like `Student_Class` is an association, not an entity... so it should be mapped as an association. That way you will have `Student.Classes` and `Class.Students` properties.

Comment: Student_Class is an association but appears in the model.

Comment: what do you mean by should be mapped as an association ? what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a conditional eager load, then you should NOT be using the *Include* method.
For loading your school object containing only the students that belong to the first class
You can do a ***Filtered Projection*** which returns an Anonymous Type object:

```
var school = context.School
                    .Where(s => s.SchoolID == 1) // or any other predicate
                    .Select(s => new 
                    {
                        School = s,
                        Students = s.Student.Where(st => st.ClassID == 1)
                    }).ToList();
```

Another way would be to ***Leverage Attach Method*** which returns EntityObject:

```
var school = context.School.Where(s => s.SchoolID == 1).First()
var sourceQuery = school.Students.CreateSourceQuery()
                                 .Where(st => st.ClassID == 1);
school.Students.Attach(sourceQuery);
```

For a more detailed discussion about this, you can also check:

[*Entity Framework: How to query data in a Navigation property table*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963046/entity-framework-how-to-query-data-in-a-navigation-property-table/3964704#3964704)